# Is there an effective way to convert PDF to SVG in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf-generation, inkscape

I'm struggling on how to convert PDF to SVG in C# WPF (Net5).

I have already read various articles and tested using InkScape.

The various PDF documents I have have a lot of text and images. Math formulas and complex characters are also included.

I needed a Vector image that didn't require any editing, so I was hoping to convert it by changing all the objects to paths.

I was able to give these options to InkScape's Command Line.

The results were very satisfactory.

Most of the characters I have are ignoring fonts and converting them to vector form whenever possible.

However,
There are a few issues.
It's taking too long to convert all the pages in my PDF.

Also, to solve these problems
When the transformation is executed by dividing the task
Conversion is not done properly and InkScape keeps running and hangs.

---

`inkscape --export-filename=d:\testtest.svg --actions="select-all;object-to-path;" --pdf-poppler --pdf-page=190 d:\Test.pdf`

The command I used is as above.

Is there any other command to embed all fonts and images inside SVG when converting PDF to SVG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> someone to me Can you recommend a separate library or commercial product that converts PDF to SVG (I can convert any object I want to a path and save it)?

[Spire.PDF](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/pdf-for-net-introduce.html) library provides the ability to convert PDF to SVG, you may give it a try.

Code example:

```
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        document.LoadFromFile("Test.pdf");
        document.SaveToFile(@"E:\Program Files\Result.svg", FileFormat.SVG);
```

For more information, visit this [link](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.PDF/Spire.PDF-Program-Guide/Conversion/Convert-PDF-to-SVG-Scalable-Vector-Graphics-in-C-VB.NET.html).